# How do you set extra "access names" for a Windows control object?

Tags: qtp, inspect, pywinauto

Is it possible to set Windows access names for form controls on a dialog?  If so, what is the API call to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Programmatic .NET names can be obtained by WM_GETCONTROLNAME message. It's implemented in [the clone of pywinauto](https://code.google.com/r/pjquirk-dotnetnames/source/browse). It works for Windows Forms (not WPF).